# No compatible version found: babel-plugin-transform-decorators@^6.13.0

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs

Apparently all out of sudden, I get the following error when I run `npm install`:

```
npm ERR! No compatible version found: babel-plugin-transform-decorators@^6.13.0
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! 6.8.0, 6.6.5, 6.6.4, 6.6.0, 6.5.0, 6.5.0-1, 6.4.0, 6.3.13, 6.2.4, 6.1.18, 6.1.17, 6.1.10, 6.1.5, 6.1.4, 6.0.14, 6.0.2
```

I have the following dependencies in `package.json`. I have tried updating the babel packages to the latest versions, as well as installing babel-plugin-transform-decorators@6.13.0, but still I get this error.

Does anybody know why, have a solution or face the same issues?

It seems to me from [this page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-decorators) that the 6.13.0 version was published 14 hours ago. However, `npm install babel-plugin-transform-decorators` installs the previous version of that package (6.8.0). Isn't the 6.13.0 available yet?

I use Node 6.0.0 on Windows, and npm 3.8.6.

Thanks in advance!

```
{
"babel": "6.3.26",
"babel-core": "6.5.2",
"babel-cli": "^6.7.7",
"babel-loader": "6.2.3",
"babel-polyfill": "6.6.1",
"babel-preset-es2015": "6.5.0",
"babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "6.3.13",
"babelify": "7.2.0",
"browserify": "13.0.0",
"chai-enzyme": "0.4.2",
"chai-jquery": "2.0.0",
"cheerio": "0.20.0",
"deep-freeze": "0.0.1",
"enzyme": "2.2.0",
"express": "4.13.4",
"fetch": "1.0.1",
"http-proxy": "1.13.2",
"immutable": "3.7.6",
"isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
"jquery": "2.2.1",
"jsfmt": "0.5.3",
"moment": "2.11.2",
"path": "0.12.7",
"react": "0.14.7",
"react-document-title": "2.0.1",
"react-dom": "0.14.7",
"react-redux": "4.4.0",
"react-router": "2.0.0",
"react-router-redux": "4.0.0",
"react-scroll": "1.0.3",
"redux": "3.3.1",
"redux-form": "4.2.0",
"redux-thunk": "2.0.1",
"request": "2.69.0",
"scroll-behavior": "0.3.2",
"sinon": "1.17.3",
"webpack": "1.12.13",
"whatwg-fetch": "0.11.0",
"chokidar": "git+https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar.git#1.4.2"
}
```

Comment: I don't see babel-plugin-transform-decorators as part of your package.json - is it a dependency of another package?

Comment: I think so!

Now it works, so it might just be that babel-plugin-transform-decorators wasn't available at npm ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works, without any changes, so it might just be that babel-plugin-transform-decorators wasn't available at npm ... ?

Answer (score 1):

I thought you had a wrong cache in your `~/.npm` directory. This kind of issue can be fixed by `npm cache clear`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that next time.